# D3 scrolling on time scale axis

Tags: d3.js, babeljs

I am trying to create a scrollable diagram with time on x axis. When I scroll I do not why it is also zooming.

Here below is a codepen (try uncommenting the linear scale to see the difference).

With linear scale it is scrolling when I scroll. And it does not zoom at the same time.

http://codepen.io/bennekrouf/pen/jqvqNZ

```
let xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([-width/2, width/2]).range([0, width])
```

But my problem is with the time scale precisely : when I scroll it is also zooming.

```
let xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([ timeDomainStart, timeDomainEnd ]).range([ 0, width ]).clamp(true);
```

The only difference in the scale function...

Thanks for your help

Comment: I added some information

Answer (score -1):

Removing .clamp(true) fixed the problem

Comment: please look at the the seconde code line in the question.

Comment: that's nice but it isn't in the codepen you provided

Comment: It was in the codepen. I just saved the correct version. Any well formed mind understand what means "removing ... fix the problem" ... when you add back the pb appears again...

Comment: Well any well informed mind wouldn't overwrite the codepen in the question, making the question not make sense at all as you provide working code. I would recommend changing it back in the question then update your answer with the working code.